# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\esupport\application\controllers\order.php on line 234

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am learning CodeIgniter with the following code:

```
private function getdbdate($date){
    $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    return  $myDateTime->format('Y/m/d');
}

private function getviewdate($date){
    $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    return  $myDateTime->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

This code gives me a fatal error:

> fatal error:-call to a member function format() in C:\xampp\htdocs\esupport\application\controllers\order.php on line 234

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$myDateTime` is `false`, using `var_dump`:

```
var_dump($myDateTime);
```

`DateTime::createFromFormat()` [returns false](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), in case an error occured.